# jQuery get all div from response

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a rails application where I get the following response when I use jQuery `get` function. I have to get all div elements with `id='users_belonging_to_project'`.

As you can see there are multiple divs with same id. I want to get the whole html() for those ids.

As it is returned from response, I used `$(data).find("div[id^='users_belonging_to_project']")` which is not giving the array of divs.

```
<div id='i_1' class='clicked'>A</div>
<div id='users_belonging_to_project' class='demo-container'>
    <div id='2' class='user_clicked'>
        tm@gmail.com
    </div>
</div>
<div id='i_2' class='clicked'>B</div>
<div id='users_belonging_to_project' class='demo-container'>
    <div id='2' class='user_clicked'>
        tm@gmail.com
    </div>
</div>
<div id='i_3' class='clicked'>dsf</div>
<div id='users_belonging_to_project' class='demo-container'>
    <div id='3' class='user_clicked'>
        tm1@gmail.com
    </div>
</div>
<div id='i_4' class='clicked'>fd</div>
<div id='users_belonging_to_project' class='demo-container'>
    <div id='2' class='user_clicked'>
        tm@gmail.com
    </div>
    <div id='3' class='user_clicked'>
        tm1@gmail.com
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id of an element is supposed to be unique, thus `getElementById` returns one element and jQuery is itself not looking for more than one element with the same id. Change this from id-s to some other attribute and select by that attribute. You can use an HTML5 attribute like `data-identifier` or some other `data-*` attribute that you like.

Answer (score 0):

The id of an element should be unique.Instead of Id use class which will give you array